# Maximum and minimum probability of two events occurring together

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let Events $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ have probabilities $\text{P(A)} $ and $\text{P(B)} $ of occurring respectively. The correlation between them is not known. What are the maximum and minimum probabilities that both Events $\text{A}$ and  $\text{B}$  will occur?

**My attempt:**

The minimum probability would occur when the events were completely independent of each other, or, $\text{P(A)} \cdot \text{P(B)} $.

The maximum probability, I think, would occur when the less probable event was completely dependent on the more probable one. If Event $\text{B} $ *always* occurs when Event $\text{A} $ occurs, then the probability of both occurring together is just $\text{P(A)} $.

Hence, the maximum probability of both events occurring is $\text{P(A)} $ or $\text{P(B)} $, whichever is higher.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: For your first attempt: what if $A$ is "the coin is heads" while $B$ is "the coin is tails"? Your second attempt is very close, but try a specific example to see what you need to modify.

Comment: You want to bound $P(A \cap B)$ and you know that $A \cap B \subset A$ and $A \cap B$ subset $B,$ so by monotonicity, $P(A\cap B) \leq \min(P(A), P(B)),$ if you make the inequality an equality by choosing particular $A$ and $B,$ you found your upper bound. On the other hand, what would happen if $A \cap B = \varnothing$?